# Regular expression finding letters and specific optional characters

Tags: regex, db2

I need a regular expression that matches strings with at least one letter `A-Z` and, optionally, any number and combination of `.-¤` (dot, dash and "sun"(what's it called in English?)).

Matched strings would be

```
A

AB

A-.

¤A
```

but NOT

```
-.

¤
```

since they don't have any letters.

My first try was of course `^[A-Z¤-.]*$` but that matches strings without letters as well.

`[A-Z]+` matches strings with at least one letter

`[¤.-]*` matches strings that might have `¤.-` in them

I've tried to combine these two last in a number of ways but haven't managed to solve my problem.

Is there a way to combine these two last regexp when I can't expect any particular order between the letters and the characters ¤.- and at the same time exclude any other characters?

Maybe groups or non-capturing groups has something to do with it, but I don't yet fully understand those.

PS I'm implementing this with the DB2 function `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^[A-Z.¤-]*[A-Z][A-Z.¤-]*$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z.¤-]*` - 0+ uppercase letters, `.`, `¤` or `-`
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `[A-Z.¤-]*`  - 0+ uppercase letters, `.`, `¤` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

See how [this regex matches sample strings](https://regex101.com/r/pcJgD1/1).